# Installing freenx by Centos 6.3

Tags: centos

When installing freenx server problem, complaining that there is no /usr/lib64/nx.

Established as follows:

```
> yum install nx freenx
```

But in the console log:

```
[root@q182 ~]# yum install nx freenx
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.netcologne.de
 * epel: mirror.imt-systems.com
 * extras: mirror.netcologne.de
 * rpmforge: mirror1.hs-esslingen.de
 * updates: mirror.netcologne.de
Setting up Install Process
Package nx-3.5.0-2.1.el6.centos.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package freenx is obsoleted by freenx-server, trying to install freenx-server-0.7.3-18.el6.x86_64 instead
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package freenx-server.x86_64 0:0.7.3-18.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/lib64/nx for package: freenx-server-0.7.3-18.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/lib64/nx for package: freenx-server-0.7.3-18.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: freenx-server-0.7.3-18.el6.x86_64 (atrpms)
           Requires: /usr/lib64/nx
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
[root@q182 ~]#
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `--enablerepo=atrpms-bleeding` to your yum command and the nx dependency will install from there.